# Changing color of GeometryDrawing in DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I'm having trouble changing the color of GeometryDrawing which was placed inside a DrawingVisual using the DrawingContext of the DrawingVisual in the following way:

```
   using (DrawingContext ctx = myRenderSurface.RenderOpen())
            {
                for (int y = -500; y <= 500; y += 40)
                {
                    for (int x = -500; x <= 500; x += 40)
                    {
                        ctx.DrawEllipse(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)x, (byte)y, (byte)10)), null, new Point(x, y), 15, 15);
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I now want to do a hit-testing and change the color of a GeometryDrawing (the Brush) it does not get reflected when I render the DrawingVisual to a RenderTargetBitmap:

```
        protected override void OnMouseMove( MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            base.OnMouseMove( e );

            if( e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed )
            {
                aTranslateTransform.X -= LastMouseXY.X - e.GetPosition( null ).X;
                aTranslateTransform.Y -= LastMouseXY.Y - e.GetPosition( null ).Y;

                InvalidateVisual();
                LastMouseXY = e.GetPosition( null );
            }
            else
            {
                Point pt = e.GetPosition( this );
                DrawingGroup dGroup = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( myRenderSurface );
                EnumDrawingGroup( dGroup, pt );
            }

            ReRender();
        }

// Enumerate the drawings in the DrawingGroup.
            public void EnumDrawingGroup(DrawingGroup drawingGroup, Point pt)
            {
                DrawingCollection drawingCollection = drawingGroup.Children;

                // Enumerate the drawings in the DrawingCollection.
                foreach (Drawing drawing in drawingCollection)
                {
                    // If the drawing is a DrawingGroup, call the function recursively.
                    if (drawing.GetType() == typeof(DrawingGroup))
                    {
                        EnumDrawingGroup((DrawingGroup)drawing, pt);
                    }
                    else if( drawing.GetType() == typeof( GeometryDrawing ) )
                    {
                        GeometryDrawing aDrawing = (GeometryDrawing) drawing;

                        // Determine whether the hit test point falls within the geometry.
                        if( aDrawing.Geometry.FillContains( pt ) )
                        {
                            // Perform action based on hit test on geometry.
                            aDrawing.Brush = Brushes.White;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

So my question is, if there is a difference between the objects in the drawing list of the DrawingVisual or if there is some kind of backing-mechanism where I don't get real access to the objects created by the DrawingContext?

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at the line `aDrawing.Brush = Brushes.White;` to see if it is ever hit?

Comment: Hi Clement. Yes of course - it is hit. I also tried to set every value to White but it also didn't work.

Comment: And you don't get any InvalidOperationException that says that the object cant be modified?

Comment: No. I read something that the Geometry is immutable and every time I change the object I should remove the old Geometry and add the new Geometry. I was also looking if the Geometry is freezed, but nothing. I made some ImageDrawing where I put the Drawing (with the Geometry) inside and Image (as ImageSource), and there it works.